# JPQL - implement conditional logic based on most recent element

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm new to JPA and Spring data. I would like to implement a function with the following logic in my ordering system:

1. If no order after given timestamp, return 1
2. otherwise return last order's counter+1

Can I implement such logic with Pure JPQL?

Order entity:

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private Integer counter;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp creationTimestamp;

    ...
```

OrderRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, UUID> {

    // TODO what goes after else?
    @Query("select case when count(o) < 1 then 1 else ... from Order o where o.creationTimestamp > :timestamp order by o.creationTimestamp desc")
    Integer nextCounter(@Param("timestamp") Timestamp timestamp);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to what the exact use case is. If you could rely on the fact that the counters for orders created after the instant provided as the parameter are increasing, you could simply select `NVL(MAX(o.counter), 0) + 1`, or event `COUNT(o) + 1`. I understand this is not the case.

What you want could be achieved with a subquery as follows:

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(o.counter), 0) + 1
FROM Order o
WHERE o.creationTimestamp = (
    SELECT MAX(o.creationTimestamp) 
    FROM Order o 
    WHERE o.creationTimestamp > :timestamp
)
```